# The PyQt5 programme automatically stops working after some time when using setTextCursor()

Tags: python, linux, qt, pyqt5, pyaudio

I have a **PyQt5 GUI** that is in charge of taking voice input from the user and converting it to text.

Everything was fine until I was told to add a new feature where the user can edit text while speaking. The cursor should not move to the start or end of a paragraph; it should stay where it is, and the text should come as it did before, so the user can edit text while speaking.

So when I add cursor positioning code my program runs for few minutes and breaks or quits window without any errors in console*(terminal).* When I remove cursor code it works.

My `VoiceWorker()` class inherited from `QThread()`:

```
class VoiceWorker(QtCore.QThread):

    textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    sig_started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def run(self) -> None:

        self.sig_started.emit()
        mic = PyAudio()

        stream = mic.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                            rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

        while not self.stopped:
            try:
                data = stream.read(4096, exception_on_overflow=False)
                if recognizer.AcceptWaveform(data):
                    text = recognizer.Result()
                    cursor = txtbox.textCursor()
                    pos = cursor.position()
                    print(f"\n Cursor position : {pos} \n")
                    speech = text[14:-3]+" "
                    print(f"\n {speech=} \n")
                    self.textChanged.emit(speech)
                    cursor.movePosition(cursor.End)
                    txtbox.setTextCursor(cursor)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"\n {e} \n")
                break
```

and I've connected **VoiceWorker** thread to my `QTextEdit()`

```
voice_thread = VoiceWorker()
voice_thread.textChanged.connect(txtbox.insertPlainText)
```

When I run this programme on a Windows system, it closes without any errors, but on a Linux system, it closes with this error: "`segmentation fault (core dumped)`". This problem occurs only when I add cursor code.

I don't know why this is happening; please help me to solve this issue.

I tried to search on Google but no luck becouse I didn't understand why It's happening.

Comment: UI elements are not thread safe. You cannot access them from external threads, you **must** use signals for that

Comment: Hello @musicamante Yes I've used signals for updating my `QTextEdit` and for starting my loop

Comment: Do I have to use signals for `textCursor` too? To change textCursor position?

Comment: Hello, @musicamante, could you please assist me in changing the `textCursor` position using signals?

Comment: You must use signals for *all* things related the gui, including the text cursor. The thread should theoretically know absolutely nothing about the GUI, nor have any reference to it. In any case, that is irrelevant: for what you need, the existing signal is more than enough, just do all the rest (cursor position, replacement, movement, etc) in the function connected to that signal.

Comment: @musicamante Can you provide some example how it would be done in existing signals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've figured out a solution to the above problem, and thanks to [***Musicamante***](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2001654/musicamante) for giving a suggestion about

> *for what you need, the existing signal is more than enough, just do all the
> rest (cursor position, replacement, movement, etc) in the function
> connected to that signal.*

So this is my final code. It looks like it is able to set text at the end of a paragraph, and it sets the cursor at the same position as it was before.

```py
class VoiceWorker(QtCore.QThread):

    textChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    sig_started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def run(self) -> None:

        self.sig_started.emit()
        mic = PyAudio()

        stream = mic.open(format=FORMAT, channels=CHANNELS,
                            rate=RATE, input=True, frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)

        while not self.stopped:
            try:
                data = stream.read(4096, exception_on_overflow=False)
                if recognizer.AcceptWaveform(data):
                    text = recognizer.Result()
                    speech = text[14:-3]+" "
                    print(f"\n {speech=} \n")
                    self.textChanged.emit(speech)
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"\n {e} \n")
                break
```

```py
voice_thread = VoiceWorker()
voice_thread.textChanged.connect(changeCursor)
```

and this is my pyqtslot

```py
@pyqtSlot(str)
def changeCursor(text):
    cursor = txtbox.textCursor()
    pos = cursor.position()
    print(f"\n Cursor position : {pos} \n")
    cursor.movePosition(cursor.End)
    cursor.insertText(text)
    cursor.setPosition(pos)
    txtbox.setTextCursor(cursor)
```